# How large a sample will be ? (Standard deviation, probability of the error)

Tags: probability, standard-error, sample

Suppose we want to estimate the average speed of cars traveling on a highway, and we want to be able to assert with probability 0.99 that the error of our estimate will be at most 3 miles per hour. How large a sample will we need if it can be assumed that $\sigma =$ 7,1 miles per hour$?

Comment: Is this [tag:self-study]? Please read the description, and if it fits, add the tag. Otherwise ignore, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a confidence interval on the mean with known variance, that therefore can be solved using z-scores. The confidence interval is:

$$\bar{x}\pm z_{\alpha}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$.

For 99% probability, $z_{\alpha}= 2.575829$ and what you want is that $z_{\alpha}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}<3\text{ mph}$. Therefore:

$$\sqrt{n}>z_{\alpha}\frac{\sigma}{3}$$
$$n>z_{\alpha}^2\frac{\sigma^2}{3^2}=2.57^2\frac{7,1^2}{3^2}=37.16$$

Then, you should have a sample larger than 37.

And for a final check, we must remember that one assumption of the formula for the confidence interval we used is that sample size is large enough for the mean to be normally distributed. Here we can see that this assumption holds enough (n>30) so we can see our result as reasonably accurate.